# 2D partitioned cumulative sum

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, matrix, subsequence

#### Challenge

Given a matrix **M** with **r** rows and **c** columns, and two Boolean lists **V** of length **r** and **H** of length **c**, calculate the partitioned cumulative vertical and horizontal sums.

#### Rules

- **r** and **c** are greater than or equal to one
- **H** and **V** begin with a true value
- The values in **M** are within your language's reasonable numeric domain.
- Partitioning and summing begins in the top left corner.

#### Walk through

Given **M**:

```
┌──────────────┐
│ 1  2  3  4  5│
│ 6  7  8  9 10│
│11 12 13 14 15│
│16 17 18 19 20│
└──────────────┘
```

**H**: `1 0 1 0 0`

**V**: `1 1 0 1`

Split **M** into groups of columns, beginning a new group at every true value of **H**

```
┌─────┬────────┐
│ 1  2│ 3  4  5│
│ 6  7│ 8  9 10│
│11 12│13 14 15│
│16 17│18 19 20│
└─────┴────────┘
```

Split each group of columns into groups of rows, beginning a new group at every true value of **V**:

```
┌─────┬────────┐
│ 1  2│ 3  4  5│
├─────┼────────┤
│ 6  7│ 8  9 10│
│11 12│13 14 15│
├─────┼────────┤
│16 17│18 19 20│
└─────┴────────┘
```

Cumulatively sum each cell horizontally:

```
┌─────┬────────┐
│ 1  3│ 3  7 12│
├─────┼────────┤
│ 6 13│ 8 17 27│
│11 23│13 27 42│
├─────┼────────┤
│16 33│18 37 57│
└─────┴────────┘
```

Cumulatively sum each cell vertically:

```
┌─────┬────────┐
│ 1  3│ 3  7 12│
├─────┼────────┤
│ 6 13│ 8 17 27│
│17 36│21 44 69│
├─────┼────────┤
│16 33│18 37 57│
└─────┴────────┘
```

Result:

```
┌──────────────┐
│ 1  3  3  7 12│
│ 6 13  8 17 27│
│17 36 21 44 69│
│16 33 18 37 57│
└──────────────┘
```

#### Additional test cases

**M**:

```
┌───────────┐
│15 11 11 17│
│13 20 18  8│
└───────────┘
```

**H**: `1 0 0 1` **V**: `1 0`

Result:

```
┌───────────┐
│15 26 37 17│
│28 59 88 25│
└───────────┘
```

**M**:

```
┌─┐
│7│
└─┘
```

Result (**H** and **V** must be `1`):

```
┌─┐
│7│
└─┘
```

**M**:

```
┌──┐
│ 3│
│-1│
│ 4│
└──┘
```

**V**: `1 1 0` (**H** must be `1`)

Result:

```
┌──┐
│ 3│
│-1│
│ 3│
└──┘
```

**M**:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│10    7.7 1.9 1.5 5.4  1.2 7.8 0.6 4.3 1.2  4.5 5.4 0.3│
│ 2.3  3.8 4.1 4.5 1    7.7 3   3.4 6.9 5.8  9.5 1.3 7.5│
│ 9.1  3.7 7.2 9.8 3.9 10   7.6 9.6 7.3 6.2  3.3 9.2 9.4│
│ 4.3  4.9 7.6 2   1.4  5.8 8.1 2.4 1.1 2.3  7.3 3.6 6  │
│ 9.3 10   5.8 9.6 5.7  8.1 2.1 3.9 4   1.3  6.3 3.1 9  │
│ 6.6  1.4 0.5 6.5 4.6  2.1 7.5 4.3 9   7.2  2.8 3.6 4.6│
│ 1.7  9.9 2.4 4.5 1.3  2.6 6.4 7.8 6.2 3.2 10   5.2 8.9│
│ 9.9  5.3 4.5 6.3 1.4  3.1 2.3 7.9 7.8 7.9  9.6 4   5.8│
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

**H**: `1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0`

**V**: `1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0`

Result:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│10   17.7 19.6  1.5  6.9  1.2  7.8  0.6  4.9  1.2  4.5  5.4  5.7│
│12.3 23.8 29.8  6   12.4  8.9 10.8  4   15.2  7   14    6.7 14.5│
│21.4 36.6 49.8 15.8 26.1 18.9 18.4 13.6 32.1 13.2 17.3 15.9 33.1│
│25.7 45.8 66.6 17.8 29.5 24.7 26.5 16   35.6 15.5 24.6 19.5 42.7│
│35   65.1 91.7 27.4 44.8 32.8 28.6 19.9 43.5 16.8 30.9 22.6 54.8│
│ 6.6  8    8.5  6.5 11.1  2.1  7.5  4.3 13.3  7.2  2.8  3.6  8.2│
│ 8.3 19.6 22.5 11   16.9  4.7 13.9 12.1 27.3 10.4 12.8  8.8 22.3│
│18.2 34.8 42.2 17.3 24.6  7.8 16.2 20   43   18.3 22.4 12.8 32.1│
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
Zœṗ@+\€Ẏð/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q6OSHO6c7aMc8alrzcFff4Q36////j46ONtQx0jHWMdExjdWJNtMx17HQsdQxNAByDA11DI10DI11DE10DEGyhmY6huY6hhY6hpY6RgaxIBEdAx0QBisHswxjYwE) and [The Last Test Case](https://tio.run/##ZZE9TgQxDIV7TpGeKMRxfjYdHXcgpKRBewFaDkBDwSUotoUWcZDlIoFnewcQ0ijyxJ@fn5272/3@fq3rj6fj6/Pl@c3nw8vx7fH9cHG11hpjUAzRuxaadxQ6juJdCRlRQmLnXQzVuxzY7vKGxMDTu5GQYpA5kOVpk2VEDLyiQQHXFWEgBRIdhQy8oUUHxOLH/FVcVkQMoYQ0407oDA1xmFEkeEIhoa@03KFD0sEkYhNjwDVEtcGnluazImpbOZmtrOLiRTQIsGhU1JCupyBfgFerbvor1qNNm3RaWXKFBKFjRx8xnLdtJfWa7WFsD@nHc4LTrqPIstnKqz5fNq82fjchibo60Nnn9GfjG4zy0emk//Ef8Dce5/wC)
 (With a `G` at the end for readability).

Input is taken as a list `[M, H, V]`.

### Explanation

```
Zœṗ@+\€Ẏð/  Input: [M, H, V]
        ð/  Insert the previous (f) as a dyadic link
            Forms f( f(M, H) , V)
            For f(x, y):
Z             Transpose x
 œṗ@          Partition the rows of x^T at each true in y
    +\€       Compute the cumulative sums in each partition
       Ẏ      Tighten (Joins all the lists at the next depth)
```

Comment: You can use a footer like [this](https://tio.run/##ZZExTgQxDEV7TpGeKMRxktl0dHsHQkoatBegpaGjoeASW9BCu9qDLBcJfNs7gJBGkSd@/v527u92u4c5b44vp/fX68vbz8f96eP58HY1D0/bOXvvFEP0bgmLdxQajuJdCRlRQmLjXQzVuxzY7vKKxMDDu56QYpA5kOVplWVEDLyiQQHXFGEgBRINhQx8QYsGiMWP@au4rIgYQglpxp3QGRriMKNI8IRCQl9puUGHpINJxCbGgGuIaoPPLc1nRbSs5WS2soqLF9EgwKJRUUO6noJ8AV6tetFfsR5t2qTTypIrJAgdG/qI4bxuK6nXbA9je0g/nhOcNh1Fls1WXvX5snm18ZsJSdTUgc4@hr/o32CUj84n/Y//gL/xOMYX) so that you don't have to tamper with your actual code.

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

Takes ist of **V H M** as argument.

```apl
{⍉⊃,/+\¨⍺⊂⍵}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVA7TkMxEOw5xZY8AY53/Xu@C00kBE0kaBGiIRISkZ7EMegogIYyR/FFwuzaiVDear0745lx1g@bq5vH9eb@7nC4ba/vT215a7vt5eriev/Rlt@2e2nLz/MKKJ0zMXniSU/ezh7nSKkt3235Ej@dGcsPRucKReCciNm@QhxIgM009wvTKGIQyxAZMqhg@0D7T6Z4tBi/Ywg@TUz8vwObYagJPBUHc1dRiZKL6ILdTN5lii7YHAfmMQsqAI@Obc@moLtIGToJWNU9eAW9ghfAKNCpwIJ6qW3GmNEDrgnWAbNSotlG0JQjEIomOkNILCBbiGJBMqlOUMnunNHLILO5RcuSjc5Uccom6pEuo6LaOLa0al0tq1jWbChDsUJJLFx/m6g1Zv2v@gOkhxCYV6Mne0cyazUMp@TVrhXjwUKjT38)

`{`…`}/` insert (reduce by) the following anonymous function, where the term in the left is represented by ⍺ and the term on the right is represented by ⍵. Due to APL functions being right associative, this is therefore **V** *f* (**H** *f* **M**).

`⍺⊂⍵` partition ⍵ according to ⍺

`+\¨` cumulative sum of each part

`,/` reduce by concatenation (this encloses the result to reduce rank)

`⊃` disclose

`⍉` transpose

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + numpy, <strike>143</strike> <strike>138</strike> <strike>117</strike> <strike>115</strike> <strike>110</strike> 108 bytes

<sup>-21 bytes thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)!</sup>

```python
lambda M,*L:reduce(lambda m,l:vstack(map(lambda p:cumsum(p,0),split(m,*where(l)))).T,L,M)
from numpy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVPLjtpAELzzFS2fbDI78jxsY6Tc97Aol4gL8cGBcbCCwbJNIr6eTPe02Q2LhNVTVV1dPYb@Nh0vZ31vvv64n@ru56GGjVi@rQd3uO5dzFAnTus/41Tvf8dd3c9ov95fu/Haxb1IEzH2p3aKO7H8e3SD70z8R34Xb2KTLJrh0sH52vU3aLv@MkzL@8E1MLlxijcCXgVsk/UCmssArYAR2jM4L3dDPbk42rxuI6ShH9rz5OkvEK2jx3nHDtWurWZwwVz07TqhNJwaHLb16mTxJHuJYAkmneEFJauH@vzLxUqAVokc3HisexdbAVkiYOfhVEB4plUAGKuS2WCob/FupzIPKv4WpDXeFKUrAauqevejdj492xQsJP6ZNIi@EGc/6kKoT4lS6ScVsvC0LPHhI2bSYqWR8LlSmQuw0jBmH5JU0jCNlEGllYp59bA1WBmU5zggQ10ZJAYlGVqU2GhQXuCIEkWG8nC@HMEcK4NGGmmDGKktbYuAxSaSa2xUOJdGrnCCDotRZdjMoDiXaYhh5pGcM8eqeLQrjmWDOWUhD4Vi8sixR4XryZDPUJ5zdxGOFD3lbXXYli45p3eFE0ucQ4Ht47Z0yGr5xfA96PfMGpOWYRW6bMPteXh9lrPy@iUbUVWGBGH355/i/FSf6@qjMP3vz5Dc/wE)

Comment: ask for partition, split, and cumsum once, transpose, repeat.

Comment: @Adám Thanks, I didn't think of that for some reason.

Comment: I liked the list lookup of two functions anyway :)

Comment: Please make header "Python 3 + numpy"

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>15</s>  14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
œṗ+\€Ẏ
ḢçÐ€Zð⁺
```

A dyadic link taking `H,V` on the left and `M` on the right and returning the resulting matrix.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Ic7p2vHPGpa83BXH9fDHYsOLz88AciLOrzhUeOu////R0cb6hjogLBBrA6QDebFxoLFjXSMdUx0TIHiZjrmOhY6ljqGYEVAVUY6hsY6hiY6hiBZQzMdQ3MdQwsdQ0sdI4PYWAA)**

Alternatively as a single line also for 14: `Ḣœṗ+\€Ẏ$¥Ð€Zð⁺`

#### How?

```
œṗ+\€Ẏ - Link 1: partition and cumSum: list of partition bools, list of values
œṗ     - partition (the values) at truthy indexes (of the bools)
    €  - for €ach part:
  +\   -   cumulative reduce by addition
     Ẏ - tighten (flattens back into a list)

ḢçÐ€Zð⁺ - Main link: list of lists, [H,V]; list of lists, M
      ⁺ - perform this twice:
     ð  - [it's a dyadic chain for the second pass, first pass is dyadic implicitly]
Ḣ       -   head, pop it & modify (so H the first time, V the second)
  Ð€    -   map across right: (M the first time, the intermediate result the second)
 ç      -     the last link (1) as a dyad
    Z   -   transpose the result (do the rows first time, and the columns the second)
```

---

Previous:

```
œṗ@+\€Ẏ
ç€Zç€⁵Z
```

A full program printing a representation of the result.

Comment: Whoa -50% from previous Jelly answer!

Comment: Whoa what? Wow. I really need to study how you did this... Incredible compared to mine!

Comment: Oh this is doing the two directions separately, right? Smart.

Comment: I think it's doing *roughly* the same thing...

Comment: Good method. Means I can beat this with APL. I've got 14 bytes.

Comment: @Adám ...I'm almost certain there is a shorter way by taking `H,V` as one argument ad using reduce, but I can't quite work out how.

Comment: I am amazed that Jelly is so golfable - first 31 then 14 and now a 10...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I thought a reduce would be available for less, but did not think to start with all 3 inputs in 1 list - that was key.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 19 bytes

```
,!ix"0GYs@12XQ!g]v!
```

Inputs are `M` (matrix), `H` (column vector), `V` (column vector). The row separator is `;`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYo9D8IgAAV3f8XRuQMPKLRhcXPupiEMTsaknTTGf48fYXnJ3b39@txaG839PdjT5XGUO6/mVl@mtSIcnsCUiSRmFmQzEnLIo4C@TRElNKMFZ@uhKPO7/bdzV/UD) Or verify all test cases: [1](https://tio.run/##LYo9D8IgAAV3f8XRuQMPKLRhcXPupiEMTsaknTTGf48fYXnJ3b39@txaG839PdjT5XGUO6/mVl@mtSIcnsCUiSRmFmQzEnLIo4C@TRElNKMFZ@uhKPO7/bdzV/UD), [2](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X0cxs0LJwD2y2MHQKCJQMT22TPH//2hDUwVDQzAyt1YwNFYwMlAwtFCwiOWKNrRWMAAjQygnFgA), [3](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X0cxs0LJwD2y2MHQKCJQMT22TPH/f3MuQy5DAA), [4](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X0cxs0LJwD2y2MHQKCJQMT22TPH//2hjawVdQ2sFk1guQ65oIAOIDGIB), [5](https://tio.run/##ZVA9SwUxEOz9FXnWErKbzeZCGjtrO@VxhZUIWikP//05O3fKA@Fy@zWZmc3Hy9f7tt2d3r5vy8Pz573o0@Ppdb2ctu0sJfXck@SB01LLhqjoLalkT5YraztmJdeZFM0KgGXhQEgRPUsOoobZiD5wPbeJQjDsKBT5ghxqIewoHbHinqJdUQfEJpUNuAApqIy0C5iUHoU2Oq148hCpQbqLO2I/0EI9ox0nXtKYSJ20BU4dx0Ioxy6N4oN2lXbjISAh4BzgCgd2LKihjjpebF9CdxsK@TGJb9ylUT0k65/7wXsRwzN3XG/OMlPhJ79/@Z9f467RZf0B).

#### Explanation

This does the cumulative sum horizontally, then vertically.

```
,          % Do the following twice
  !        %   First time this inputs M implicitly. Transpose. Second time
           %   it transposes the result of the horizontal cumulative sum
  ix       %   Input H (first time) or V (second time). Delete it; but gets
           %   copied into clipboard G
  "        %   For each column of the matrix
    0G     %     Push most recent input: H (first time) or V (second)
    Ys     %     Cumulative sum. This produces a vector of integer values
           %     such that all columns (first time) or rows (second) of M 
           %     with the same value in this vector should be cumulatively
           %     summed
    @      %     Push current column of M transposed (first time) or M after
           %     horizontal cumulative sum (second time)
    12XQ   %     Cumulative sum. Gives a cell array of row vectors
    !g     %     Join those vectors into one row vector
  ]        %   End
  v        %   Concatenate the row vectors vertically into a matrix
  !        %   Transpose. This corrects for the fact that each column vector
           %   of the matrix was cumulatively summed into a row vector
           % Implicit end. Implicit display
```

Comment: Most impressive. I guess Matlab was kinda made for stuff like this.

Comment: @Adám I'm sure APL's length won't be very different :-)

Comment: My reference implementation used to generate the test cases is 26 bytes.

Comment: @Adám Darn! APL beating Jelly? This is unacceptable! (must golf my solution... lol) xD

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Well, Jelly doesn't have both rank and depth like APL and J have.

Comment: @Adám Yeah... Jelly wasn't a great choice. I seems to me that Matrix Laboratories (MATLAB if I remember correctly?) might be a better choice for matrices :)))

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Heh, I should have gone full 3D or nD.

Comment: @Adám 3D could make a nice challenge (in the not-too-near future). The problem may be how to represent the ouput

Comment: @LuisMendo Easy; [stack of matrices](http://tryapl.org/?a=2%203%204%u2374%u237324&run). Or with [box drawing](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u236A%u2282%u23642%u22A22%203%204%u2374%u237324&run).

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

```
;@(<@(+/\);.1|:)&.>/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1krB2kHDxkFDWz9G01rPsMZKU03PTp@LKzU5I18hTcEQCA2A2BpKGwChtYKCnZVCpp6CiYLp//8A)

Input is taken as an array of boxes containing `[V, H, M]`.

### Explanation

```
;@(<@(+/\);.1|:)&.>/  Input: [V H M]
  (     g      )   /  Insert g and reduce (right-to-left)
                      Forms V g H g M = V g (H g M)
                & >     Unbox each
             |:         Transpose the right arg
          ;.1           Partition
      +/\               Reduce each prefix using addition (cumulative sum)
   <@                   Box each partition
;@                      Raze (Concatenate the contents in each box)
                &.>     Box the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 212 bytes

```
(T=Transpose;A=AppendTo;J=Flatten;f[s_]:=Block[{},t=2;r=1;w={};While[t<=Length@s,If[s[[t]]==0,r++,w~A~r;r=1];t++];w~A~r];K[x_,y_]:=Accumulate/@#&/@(FoldPairList[TakeDrop,#,f@y]&/@x);d=J/@K[#,#2];T[J/@K[T@d,#3]])&
```

**input**
[M,H,V]

> [{{15, 11, 11, 17}, {13, 20, 18, 8}}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0}]

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 164 bytes

```cs
(M,H,V)=>{int a=M.Length,b=M[0].Length,i,j;for(i=0;i<a;i++)for(j=0;j<b;j++)if(!H[j])M[i][j]+=M[i][j-1];for(i=0;i<a;i++)for(j=0;j<b;j++)if(!V[i])M[i][j]+=M[i-1][j];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNb5tAEL37V0x9AmWDwGAwwliqeonUWqpSKT1QDtgGe5EBCYirKOK3uzO7YILrkOxhmJmd9@YDmG11vy3K@Ax4tseoquBnWezLKJuQ51VIOlUd1XwLp4LvYB3xXKnqkuf7IISo3FfqJa5H0Pn1UtVxpn3d1rzIl7vieXOMgzAIGWyK4tg/V5D4k7OyZg/sSfVXrzyvIfLX2o8439cHtvHXgR52FmeplxSlwn3d48vI43d3Ktkp2uly46Vo80T58hCkoboOeIjPO18q90b4KewTRg@wCETVa87eZNBh3xNk4EMe/0VtOAQ6rR8MnZHpaA4DQ3NJzBnMNQvdhjZjeLNgoGs2A0szmfSh2gXpmgkNe5ceZgQCk0gszWASafQ56Ravkcmm7HMKBFcEEdLR5qP0LnEi3qFQrMwlvCn6EI05VLhLwiE6W1RvkurKcGuUXrSM0mWSidBYGA1HVLqg9DOyDalRuMhkUrj9Qe1mV6YgE2XOqZWO12h7sWRaIrclOd64Y9w2cclKdRqmTcISTkHrSJvmIMc0EzeLtnCMHGM3RJEulSaaty7vC23qm5ziwxEDN0l0jc5oau74XFwxX7MltuV3Z4k3103Zke9k0WpyeFY7y2ZA3ngDU/7gcOh/DqjL55hBEh2r/jHwSeOtHL94J@fpg5wjFVxoB7yJkjE4MDip1xdFCQotLY4pcfKph9oSsnZloYV7ZYD4f0UIjpTwHqQExu1zwafX@NscdHhCNCvQ1W79fivyqjjG2u@S17EyZTBVvZvQm/GZ3II3IM3kUwTTP/l1wmYyGYE9xtHue/yivAHJVM35Hw)

Basically it does exactly as specified in the OP. It first iterates to sum horizontally and then it iterates again to sum vertically.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>129 bytes</s> 119 bytes

```hs
s m v=tail$scanl(\a(x,s)->if s then x else zipWith(+)a x)[](zip m v)
t=foldr(zipWith(:))$repeat[]
f m h v=t$s(t$s m v)h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc8/a8MwEAXw3Z/iDR4keoVc@jcBd@zWrdBB1SAaGYnKjrHUYPrl3bNJKKWDEHr83okLLn/6lOY5o8OpKS6mOn@4Pql3pybK@voptsgowfeY4FP2@I7DWyxBXWmHSRurJFjauipNe0yHUV3EXut69IN3xdiqFROWP@qs5KyNMHcu9mhwOFZA8kXSBsYwYUu4IdwS7izB3BMeCI@EHYE3S8JiWBCLYmG8OhbIIlkoi91urD1PDsvk1/HLE56d7EH481iviz392n@NxXRueMEwxr5AnffS8w8)

*Saved 10 bytes thanks to @ceasedtoturncounterclockwis*

`t` (for transpose) switches rows and columns. A quick explanation:

```hs
foldr(zipWith(:))(repeat[])(r1,...,rn) =
zipWith(:) r1 (zipWith(:) r2 (... zipWith(:) rn (repeat [])))
```

Read from right to left: we browse rows from bottom to up, and push each value in its destination column.

`s` is basically a rolling sum of vectors, but resets when a True value arises in `v`

`f` sums the rows with `s` following `v` and do the same with the columns following `h`

Comment: `t=foldr(zipWith(:))(repeat[])`. Not only shorter, also much less inefficient.

Comment: @ceasedtoturncounterclockwis Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

```
(a,h,v)=>a.map(b=>b.map((e,i)=>t=h[i]?e:t+e)).map((b,j)=>t=v[j]?b:t.map((e,i)=>e+b[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 bytes

```
+\€€
œṗḊZ€⁵œṗ$€Ḋ€Ç€ÇZ€€Z€;/€€;/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw7DsJADER7zkHHSPFsQj7KTbJxSYNyAUpokGgpuAQtEtSIg4SLON6NZI3f2KM5HqbpZLYb/5enz@Z3nz@P@X0bkj@/st06@8n1e80yrOG0@mLlvjCzSBACqkXHgBIV9opYo0GLDhQ39FAAS7AC05c12IAt2CGIaqqRXCS6AA)

Gah this is way too long for Jelly xD

BTW, 11/31 bytes in this program consists of euro characters. That's over a third of the program!

Comment: Too many Euros.

Comment: @Adám My thoughts exactly :P Working with doubly partitioned matrices isn't as fun as I thought it would be, because I'm doing second-level to third-level mapping xD

Comment: Why are you wasting your money like this €-€